# group theory and dihedral groups

Tags: group-theory

if $d$ divides $2n$, show that there is a subgroup $H$ of $D_{2n}$ of order $d$.

I know if $d$ divides $2$ then by **cauchy theorem** there exists subgroup of order $2$ if $d$ divides $n$ then there is cyclic group of order $n$ but how to show if $d$ divides $2n$ then there exists subgroup of order $d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d$ divides $2n$;

If $d$ divides $n$, question become trivial since $\mathbb Z_n$ has a uniqe subgroup for all divisior of $n$ and $D_{2n}$  includes $\mathbb Z_n$ as a subgroup.

Assume $d\nmid n$; since $d|2n$ we must have $\dfrac d2 \mid n$.

Let $C$ be cyclic subgroup of $G=D_{2n}$ with order $n$ since $\dfrac d2 \mid n$, $C$ has a subgroup $H$ of order $\dfrac d2 $.

Since $H$ is uniqe in $C$, $H$ is characteristic in $C$ and $C$ is normal in $G$ so $H$ is normal in $G$.

Now, let $x\in G-C$ then $|x|=2$ and $R=H.<x>$ is a group since $H$ is normal so $|R|=d$ and we are done.

Comment: R=H what is this R? if R=H and order of R=d...but first you menstion  that order of H=d/2..and R=H...

Comment: No, it's not $R = H$, it's $R = HK$ where $K$ is the subgroup generated by $x$.

Comment: @Yasir: As Davis said, $R=HK$ where $K=<x>$ and $|K|=2$. And To be sure that $HK$ is a group, we showed that $H$ is normal in $G$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can find many of them inside the cyclic subgroup of order n. For the others, there is another family of familiar groups embedded inside $D_{2n}$.

Comment: i want help for the formal proof...

Comment: Right. And the rest is easy once you figure out what that other family is.

Comment: Problem solving is the art of reducing something difficult to something trivial.

Comment: @user54092: It is too poetic :=

Comment: @mesel What do you mean?

Comment: Let me make it a bit more plain: can you find a group of symmetries of the square inside a group of symmetries of an octagon?

Comment: i think the only subgroups are the cyclic subgroups and all other subgroups are generated by any two reflections but i m not confermed about their orders in this case

Comment: @Yasir Think about this geometrically - I can embed an square inside an octogon in such a way that every symmetry of the square is also a symmetry of the octogon. Similarly, if I have a n-sided regular polygon, I can put it  a $d$ sided polygon in it if $d | n$ so that similar relationship on the symmetries holds (just draw a side every $n/d$ sides of the bigger polygon, with lines again between the vertices). This idea can be translated into the algebraic setting, since the dihedral groups are just the symmetries of regular polygons.